# Adding Testflight SDK: missing required architecture arm64 in file libTestFlight.a

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I'm adding the Testflight SDK to my iOS project, but now I can't build the IPA for it.

The error I have is

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file     /Users/RM/Dropbox/SAM_iOS/mainApp/SAM/TestFlightSDK2/libTestFlight.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/RM/Dropbox/SAM_iOS/mainApp/SAM/TestFlightSDK2/libTestFlight.a (3 slices)
 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TestFlight", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've followed (three times) the steps detailed [here](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/ios/doc/2.0.2/), but the error keeps appearing.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 2.0.2 version of the TestFlight library does not support `arm64`.

You can either remove the `arm64` from your project and targets or use the 2.1 beta library which has support for `arm64`

Answer (score 3):

You can check which architectures are included in the a library using the `lipo` tool in Terminal:

```
lipo -info <path to library>
```

Running this on version 2.0.2 of the library, shows that it does not include the arm64 architecture:

> Architectures in the fat file: libTestFlight.a are: armv7 armv7s i386

Running the same on the 2.1.3 beta:

> Architectures in the fat file: libTestFlight.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64